# ASN.1-based network protocol fuzzer

Tags: fuzzing, asn1

I want to do network protocol-based fuzzing using a network protocol specified in ASN.1.
After investigating the available open source tools, I need to decide between the Peach community edition, Sulley and Boofuzz. But because Peach and Sulley are not in active development since last three years, I intend to use Peach's successor Boofuzz and would start building my model for it.

Would you advice me against this decision and can anyone tell me his prior experiences about the stability/performance of these tools?

Thanks.